# parsing nested (I think) JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've been trying to parse this JSON string.  I'm using JSON.NET and a snippet of the JSON, my classes and basic function calls follow:

```
{"status":"ok","apirate":"0","people":{
"Mike":{"id":"Mike","rating":"0.80","questions":"100"},
"Donald":{"id":"Donald","rating":"0.7","questions":"9"},
"Tony":{"id":"Tony","rating":"0.22","questions":"2"},
"Penelope":{"id":"Penelope","rating":"0.006","questions":"6"},
"Sarah":{"id":"Sarah","rating":"0.79","questions":"20"},
"Thomas":{"id":"Thomas","rating":"0.12","questions":"25"},
"Gail":{"id":"Gail","rating":"0.44","questions":"35"}}}
```

The classes I'm using as storage objects:

```
     public class Folks
    {
        public Folks()
        {
        }
        public String status;
        public String message; //optional
        public int apirate;
        public PeopleDetails[] people;
    }

      public class PeopleDetails 
    {
        public PeopleDetails ()
        {
        }
        public String id;
        public double rating;
        public int questions;
    }
```

And finally, what I'm doing in the code:

```
    Folks test = new Folks();
    test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Folks>(myRequest.GetResponse());
```

Status and API rate are coming through fine, message doesn't exist because there's no error and my PeopleDetails array is making an exception. (EDIT: throwing a JsonSerializationException because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly.)  I've tried putting another class/object between the two I've pasted here and I've tried different collections, and so on.

So... since this is my first time working with this (smart, pick the complex stuff the first time) can anybody point me towards a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your json is not valid. I don't now if this is a typo or your problem arouse because of this. I will edit your question.

Comment: @SAM that should have been an answer; not an edit.  Being invalid would cause the JSON parse to fail causing the problem.

Comment: _"my PeopleDetails array is making an exception"_ - what exception? Most likely you need a `Dictionary<string, PeopleDetails>` because of the array keys being strings.

Comment: I apologize for the vague description.  Frustration and lack of sleep have been taking their toll.  A Dictionary is indeed the answer.

I also edited the JSON to be correct and added the exception to the question in case this might help somebody else who lacks familiarity with this issue.

Comment: @cholisky It's important that you don't correct the mistake in the JSON so that other viewers can see the issue. There's no shame in showing a mistake as this also helps other viewers learn; we're only human after all.

Comment: @KevinHogg I wanted to correct that one because the missing brace was one that I deleted while formatting the code when I posted it.  I thought that the typo distracted from the question I was asking and wasn't part of the actual problem that I was asking about.  That being said, as a new poster on SO I appreciate the advice and will keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, your given JSON is incorrect, there is a `{` missing in the penelope record.

so the correct JSON would be

```
{"status":"ok","apirate":"0","people":{
"Mike":{"id":"Mike","rating":"0.80","questions":"100"},
"Donald":{"id":"Donald","rating":"0.7","questions":"9"},
"Tony":{"id":"Tony","rating":"0.22","questions":"2"},
"Penelope":{"id":"Penelope","rating":"0.006","questions":"6"},
"Sarah":{"id":"Sarah","rating":"0.79","questions":"20"},
"Thomas":{"id":"Thomas","rating":"0.12","questions":"25"},
"Gail":{"id":"Gail","rating":"0.44","questions":"35"}}}
```

Then, if you have a look at the structur, you may not that people is not a list but a dictionary, with the name as the key.

So, here is a working test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var json = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"apirate\":\"0\",\"people\":{\n\"Mike\":{\"id\":\"Mike\",\"rating\":\"0.80\",\"questions\":\"100\"},\n\"Donald\":{\"id\":\"Donald\",\"rating\":\"0.7\",\"questions\":\"9\"},\n\"Tony\":{\"id\":\"Tony\",\"rating\":\"0.22\",\"questions\":\"2\"},\n\"Penelope\":{\"id\":\"Penelope\",\"rating\":\"0.006\",\"questions\":\"6\"},\n\"Sarah\":{\"id\":\"Sarah\",\"rating\":\"0.79\",\"questions\":\"20\"},\n\"Thomas\":{\"id\":\"Thomas\",\"rating\":\"0.12\",\"questions\":\"25\"},\n\"Gail\":{\"id\":\"Gail\",\"rating\":\"0.44\",\"questions\":\"35\"}}}";
        var folks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Folks>(json);

        Assert.AreEqual("ok", folks.Status);
    }

    public class Folks
    {
        public Folks()
        {
            this.People = new Dictionary<string, PeopleDetails>();
        }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("apirate")]
        public int Apirate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("people")]
        public Dictionary<string, PeopleDetails> People { get; set; }
    }

    public class PeopleDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rating")]
        public decimal Rating { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("questions")]
        public int Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That's the ticket.  I'm new to both c# and JSON and have only used a Dictionary once in school a couple of years ago.  This solution worked perfectly.